# can't get the url of a image with jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup, malformedurlexception

I'm trying to get the url of a range of images like that:

```
for(Element img : document.select(".left-column .strillo-content .lazy img[src]")) {
    InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageMainUrl).openStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    images.add(bitmap);
}
```

but everytime I trying to run my app I get this warning:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: data
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:184)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:127)
```

so I have tried to print the URL and I get this:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7
```

and I can figure out why, because I'm 100% sure that the element I select is corrent and also I do the same process with other section of the website and it works..

**UPDATE 1**:
I have tried this method to decode the ´base64´ image:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageMainUrl, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

but the result is the same..

Comment: I'm no expert on HTML, but it seems like the content of the image is actually embedded in the src tag, instead of pointing to an URL. You might be able to decode that on android if you store it on a byte array and pass it  to BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the data URI scheme

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

It allows to add inline data in your URI.

- Extract the base64 part of the URI and get a byte array with `parseBase64Binary`, more information here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseBase64Binary%28java.lang.String%29
- Use this array to build a `ByteArrayInputStream`
- Use your `BitmapFactory` to decode it into a `Bitmap`

**edit**

This code works, it give a 1px*1px gif image. I used `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` from `commons-codec`

```
String uri = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7";
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decodeBase64(uri.substring(uri.indexOf("data:image/gif;base64,") + "data:image/gif;base64,".length()));
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedString);
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/test.gif"));

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int length;

// copy the file content in bytes 
while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    os.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

is.close();
os.close();
```

Comment: You have to remove from imageMainUrl the prefix `data:image/gif;base64,`

Comment: What do you mean by same result ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, the MalformedURLException is now gone!

Comment: the Bitmap returned is null